# Sql table with default value will not save when passed a NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql table that has the column CreatedDate.

It's setup in the database with:

Default Value of Binding (getdate())

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Person] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Person__Creat__6XXXXXXX]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [CreatedDate]
GO
```

The insert works when I send `default` through for that column but if I send NULL I get.

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CreatedDate' column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Is there any way to get this to work so it will set the current date when null is sent through?

Comment: Could you please show the entire declaration of that column, including the constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you have set a contraint on that column and you have specified that a default value on that column is the current date `GetDate()`

Comment: So is there a better way to do this to achieve what I want which is to automatically set the date on inserts?

Comment: don't add the column in your insert query, so for example you have 2 columns(colName, dateColumn) and one of which is a date column which has a default value of `GetDate()` in your query, you can omit that column, eg `INSERT INTO tableName(colName) VALUES ('valueHere')`

Comment: Yes, leave the date column out of the INSERT entirely -- do not specify it in the list of columns, and do not include a value for it in the list of values.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, you're using the form of the INSERT statement like this:

```
 INSERT INTO TableName VALUES (Value1, Value2, . . .)
```

Instead, use this form:

```
 INSERT INTO TableName (Column1, Column2, Column4. . .) VALUES (Value1, Value2, Value4. . .)
```

Note that the second form specifies what columns you're including values for.  Just leave out any column for which you want the default value stored.

This form of the INSERT statement is *always* preferable since it is less fragile if the number or order of columns in the table changes.  It's also clearer and aids in debugging.